# Which application changes sound volume

Tags: audio, volume-control

I would like to do some 24h logging on Android phone in order to find out which application is constantly turning the volume of notifications down to zero.

I even don't know at which time point it is happening.

Are there any ready applications for that?

Comment: Hi. Please note that seeking app recommendations is off-topic here. If you are open to trying a non-app based solution, try my answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214999/96277

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the app on your phone that does that. but in my experience there are two, the problem may be in the headphone jack (a port which allows you to plug and unplug your headphone) where it has to be changed or try to change the headphone (if you are using it) because the problem may also be in the headphone plug.